# How to create custom image element with src attribute?

Tags: javascript

How to create custom image element with src attribute?

Following is the code for creating custom image tag.

```
export class ImageElement extends HTMLImageElement {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor run');
    super();
  }
}

customElements.define('image-tag', ImageElement, { extends: 'img' });
```

And then use it as

```
    customElements.whenDefined('image-tag').then(() => {
      console.log('ready!');

          const tag = document.createElement('image-tag');
               document
                 .querySelector('main')
                 ?.appendChild(tag);

          tag.setAttribute('src', 'assets/images/heroes/4.svg');

      tag.textContent = 'img'
          tag.style.width = '10rem'
          tag.style.height = '10rem'
    });
```

But the problem is that this is not getting the src attribute. ie. I'm not being able to see the image.

Also the constructor runs only if I instantiate it like this.

```
    const Img = customElements.get('image-tag')
    const img = new Img()
```

Still I'm not sure how to set the src attribute to my `image-tag` such that it displays an image!

Is there a way to create custom image tags like this using the vanilla custom elements or web components api rather than using any framework like lit, polymer?

Anybody with any idea of how to achieve this. Or even to create a custom image rendering procedure?? I have an idea to use background image for a regular div element. But this cannot be applied to other media types.. If possible share some articles about html media rendering pipeline so that I can implement this.

Comment: Wow. This is a nice idea. I also thought of having something like this.

Comment: I wish I could get rid of the old and deprecated HTML tags with my own custom elements.  But this works only for non media elements. like container tags or text elements. No one has figured out how to deal with media tags like svg, img, video etc...

Comment: Hello...? Anybody with any idea of how to achieve this. Or even to create a custom image rendering procedure?? I have an idea to use background image for a regular div element. But this cannot be applied to other media types.. If possible share some articles about html media rendering pipeline so that I can implement this.

Comment: Hi Can someone suggest any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : changed the answer to use a custom `HTMLImageElement` where you can set the `src` afterwards.

Note that the javascript has to be loaded before you can add / change the tags. It also only works in Chrome, since other browsers don't allow `extends HTMLImageElement`

You can also use Base64 by setting the `src` to `myimage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..."`

```
class HamsterImage extends HTMLImageElement {

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['src'];
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("new hamster tag created")
        this.src = "https://i0.wp.com/thehappiesthamster.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Syrian-Hamster.png?resize=256%2C256"
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (name === "src") {
            this.src = newValue
        }
    }
}

customElements.define("image-tag", HamsterImage, { extends: 'img' });

let firstImage = new HamsterImage()
document.body.appendChild(firstImage)


// change the src
firstImage.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/622595419730644992/hefYnJP_.jpg"
```

Comment: Well then How will I pass src while construction and update it later (if any changes occurs with user events)?

Comment: I mean set the src attribute dynamically at a later stage (as most apps are not static). Can I use setAttribute?

Comment: And still in the inside it is using img tag. I want to hide that. Instead I want to use my own tag while rendering the image (src attribute)

Comment: I want it to be like this <image-tag src=""></image-tag>

Comment: Hello?? Any help??

Comment: You can pass the image in the constructor using `new HamsterImage("image.jpg")`. And you can set the `src` later as you would with any image element. For example `let img = new HamsterImage();` and then `img.src = "otherimage.jpg"`

Comment: But still it will be using the native img element. Right? I want it to be like this <image-tag src=""></image-tag>  Is it possible?

Comment: I edited the answer so that you can change the `src` attribute, but it only works with `setAttribute` for some reason.

Comment: I have one more question. Check the updated answer. If it is not possible then it's ok. No worries.

Comment: Is that possible? @kokodoko

Comment: Do you mean using `.src` instead of `.setAttribute()`? In my example that didn't work, not even with the `attributeChangedCallback`. I'm sure there must be a solution for that too.

Comment: Not that. Is it possible to create a custom tag like <my-custom-img-tag src="url to some img"></my-custom-img-tag> without any nested img tag?

Comment: I was thinking about a custom img tag without any nested img tag (which is available natively). Such that it can render/paint an image on it's own. (i.e. without the need of a regular <img src="" /> tag. Cause currently in all your implementations there is a nested<img> tag inside the custom <image-tag>. Can we implement the image rendering logic without a nested <img> tag?

Comment: Can you please let me know if this is possible? I mean use the value of img stored as byte array (base64) and then create a rendering pipeline to display this with our custom <image-tag>. I know it's crazy... still I would like to know.

Comment: I have updated the answer again :) This version allows you to change the `src` of a custom `HTMLImageElement`. There is no child `img` element. It still only works in Chrome.